# Environment variable set in batch isn't expanded in shortcut

Tags: windows-7, batch, shortcuts, environment-variables, irfanview

How can I make my environment variable (set in batch file) visible in application executed right after setting this envvar?

Here's the scenario that I use:

1. In my external script (not quite important here) I create Windows shortcuts to jpg files, with the target looking like:

   ```
   %MYPHOTOSDRIVE%:\private\photos\photo001.jpg
   ```

   %MYPHOTODRIVE% should contain just a current drive letter.
2. I start IrfanView using the following BAT script (script is located in the same directory as all the .lnk files):

   ```
   set MYPHOTOSDRIVE=%cd:~0,2%
   "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "i:\private\photolinks\photo001.lnk"
   "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" /slideshow="%cd%"
   ```

The problem is that neither the single image, nor a slideshow (for the second call to IrfanView) is executed properly.

Shouldn't this "MYPHOTODRIVE" variable be expanded to a proper value upon Irfan execution? Doesn't it get the same environment as the parent script?

Comment: **(1)** Look at the Properties dialog for your picture shortcuts. Do they still have `%MYPHOTOSDRIVE%`? If that variable is not set globally (for all of Windows, not just a single console instance), then Explorer does not use it. **(2)** Try adding a line after the `set` like `echo %%MYPHOTOSDRIVE%%` to see if it is correct. **(3)** I don’t think IrfanView can take a shortcut; it won’t resolve automatically.

Comment: *1 Yes, all picture shortcuts have %MYPHOTOSDRIVE% instead of a drive letter.
*2 Env. variable is set properly when I check it this way.
*3 I was hoping that it would work the same as it does when calling another batch script from the first one. In this case this variable would be expanded to a proper value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing an environment variable to IrfanView eg:

```
C:\> i_view32.exe %%myphotosdrive%%:\private\photos\photo001.jpg
```

You are passing it a **`.LNK`** file (which is binary). IrfanView does not know how to interpret shortcut files; it only handles graphics files and such.

Your best bet is to [request](http://irfanview-forum.de/forumdisplay.php?9-Feature-Requests) that Irfan add the ability to resolve shortcut files (he is quite responsive and good at handling support questions and feature requests).

Comment: You're right. I've created a request here: http://irfanview-forum.de/showthread.php?8865-Expansion-of-environment-variables-during-runtime